# Create a Mobile "Smart Redirect"

Tags: facebook, mobile

We create Facebook applications (tabs) but the problem is that these tabs do not work on mobile devices or inside the Facebook iOS app. Companies like ShortStack and WildFire have recently started using "Smart URLs" in order to allow their Facebook apps to work on mobile devices - I'm wanting to do something similar with my apps.

I want to create a url, such as "ExampleURL.com/Facebook-Contest/" that I could post on Facebook. If someone visits that URL in a fullsize browser, I want it to direct them to the Facebook tab. However, if they vist that link from a mobile device or within the app, I want it to redirect to a mobile HTML version of the contest that I will host on my own server (outside of Facebook). This is the same way WildFire and ShortStack accomplish these "Smart URL's".

I have no experience creating re-directs, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction on how to make this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a service that generates these types of URL's - which work perfect on Facebook.

http://smarturl.it